# Facebook Graph Search order results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use this query in Facebook to get all posts of a specific page within specific range.

`https://www.facebook.com/search/posts/?q=&filters_rp_author=&filters_rp_creation_time=`

Is there any filter to order the results chronologically or reverse chronologically?

Comment: No, there is not. You will have to do sorting on your end, after you requested all the data you need.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question to format the provided link as code fragment rather than as link, since it has no use as such - please see the editing help for more information on formatting. Please edit in to provide any additional detail that's necessary to identify the specific problem. Good luck!